# Why is this "adelic quotient" isomorphic to several copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L$ be a number field, i.e. a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $\mathbb{A}_{L,f}$ be the ring of finite adeles of $L$. Let $K^p$ be a compact subgroup of $\mathbb{A}_{L,f}^{\times}$ away from $p$. Then we can form the quotient
$$
\Gamma := L^{\times} \backslash \mathbb{A}_{L,f}^{\times} / K^p.
$$
Then **when (and why?) this quotient is isomorphic to several products of $\mathbb{Z}_p$**? (i.e. $\Gamma \cong \mathbb{Z}_p^{d}$ for some positive integer $d$).

**Motivation**: I am trying to study $p$-adic $L$-function starting from Zheng Liu's lecture at MSRI this spring. There she "defined" a $p$-adic $L$-function as a particular element in $\mathrm{Meas}(\Gamma, \mathcal{O})$, i.e. the $\mathcal{O}$-valued measures on $\Gamma$, where $\mathcal{O}$ could be a (completed) valuation ring of an extension of $\mathbb{Q}_p$, and $\Gamma$ is isomorphic to several copies of $\mathbb{Z}_p$.

Then she gave several examples.

- $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}_p$.
- $\Gamma = \mathbb{Z}_p^{\times}$
- $\Gamma = T(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ for a torus $T \in \mathrm{GL}_N$.
- $\Gamma = L^{\times} \backslash \mathbb{A}_{L,f}^{\times} / K^p$ as defined in the first paragraph.

I can understand the first few examples, but got stuck on the last one. Could someone help me on this?

Thank you so much for any comments and answers!

Comment: Is it $\mathbb{A}_{L,f}$ or $\mathbb{A}_{L,f}^{\times}$?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it should be $\mathbb{A}_{L,f}^{\times}$. I have corrected them in the post. Thank you so much for pointing it out!

Comment: This is strange… suppose that $L$ is a field with a nontrivial unit and $O_L$ is a PID, and $K^p=\prod_{v \nmid p}{O_{K_v}^{\times}}$. Then we should get $(L \otimes\mathbb{Q}_p)^{\times}/L^{\times}$, thus $\prod_{v \mid p}{O_{K_v}^{\times}}/O_L^{\times}$. The “numerator” here is of the correct form – topologically speaking, at least – because of the exponential map, but the image of $O_L^{\times}$ is clearly not closed so the quotient is topologically hideous…